# React Router not working when given params

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can can't find the problem here it might be a typo but I think I have followed the documentation..

index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}></Route>
    <Route path="/match:id" component={MatchFeedComponent}></Route>
    <Route path="/user" component={UserPageComponent}></Route>
    <Route path="/comments" component={CommentHolderComponent}></Route>
    <Route path="/post-talk" component={AddTalkComponent}></Route>
    <Route path="/add-match" component={AddMatchComponent}></Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

In my

```
<Link to={{ pathname:"/match/", query: {id: this.id}}}>
```

I get:
`[react-router] Location "/match/?id=-KXKIhpF8mdWDn9C5Tnd" did not match any routes`

It works fine without any params but can't find it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "id" to be a query string param, it shouldn't appear in your route. Change to this:

```
<Route path="/match" component={MatchFeedComponent}></Route>
```

...and then just pick up the id from props.location.query inside your component

Answer (score 2):

React Router usually doesn't work with the "regular queries", at least how you've set it up. Your Router expects something like `/match/-KXKIhpF8mdWDn9C5Tnd` instead of `/match/?id=-KXKIhpF8mdWDn9C5Tnd`. Try this as your `Link`:

```
<Link to={`/match/${this.id}`}>
```

and then change your route to:

```
<Route path="/match/:id" component={MatchFeedComponent}></Route>
```